# Sizing screenshot.png without losing aspect ratio

Tags: theme-development, themes

I have been trying to size my screenshot.png for my theme to 300x255 without losing aspect ratio. I have been doing this by getting my browser window width on my laptop to a size that is proportional to 300x255 so that I will get a screenshot without distortion but has not worked.

Moreover, I am working with a fixed width layout, that has a central content area and a background. Reducing the browser window will cover the background which is not desirable.

I believe there must be an easier way to do this and would like to know if there are any tools that theme developers use to get this right. I do not have photoshop but do have gimp installed.

I would appreciate any pointers you may have in this regard.

Thanks in advance
nav

Comment: You are asking how to resize an image using GiMP?

Comment: It does not matter what image manipulation tool is used what I am looking for is a repeatable process to get a screenshot of the right size. See my answer below.

Comment: Yes, tools do matter and I like GiMP, but this is a _WordPress_ Q&A site. I don't see how this is in any way WordPress specific.

Comment: Yes in hindsight I probably should not have asked this question here forgive my ignorance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got around this problem by doing the following steps.

1. Find out screensize we will call this `<screenwidth>` and `<screenheight>` for now.
2. I made my browser fullscreen. I used Chrome for this as the header bar disappeared and I got the full screen height for my screenshot. This is not necesary however.
3. If you have got a header subtract it from the screen height. `<height> = <screenheight> - <header>.`
4. If you have a vertical scrollbar subtract this width from the width. `<width> = <screenwidth> - <scrollbar-width>`.
5. Now in most screens these days especially laptops the width is ample but the height is not in which case we have to find out the width that is proportional to the height.

Therefore, `<width-screenshot> = <height>/450 * 600` if you do not get whole number round it to the nearest even number.

1. Now we have to get an  so that we get our website show within the size `<width-screenshot>x<height>`. To calculate that we do `(<screenhieght> - <scrollbar-width> - <width-screenshot>)/2`.
2. Open up and image manipulation program choose the crop function and input the width, height and x-offset values. Then crop and save the image.
3. Open the saved image and choose the resize option and set the width to 600. The height should automatically become 450. Which is the desired size save the image.

This is a repeatable process and once you have the numbers it is just a question of reuse.

Hope that helps someone.
nav

Comment: What?  Of course you have to crop an image to get the aspect ratio you want.  You can just resize it down to 300 width and then crop to 255 height, or vice versa.  I don't understand the need for all the additional steps.

Comment: Image manipulation is not something I do regularly so my skills are not obviously up to the mark. But I have learnt a lot from all who have commented.